# Where should I put routes in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I just started to learn node.js with express 4. I have read some books and tutorials, I also cloned some sample apps from git but I still have a very basic question, which practice should I follow to write the routing(or controller)?

Some people define all the routes in app.js, and export all the functions in the controller:

app.js

```
    ....
    var homeController = require('./controllers/home');
    var userController = require('./controllers/user');
    ....
    app.get('/', homeController.index);
    app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
    app.get('/logout', userController.logOUT);
    app.get('/doStuff', userController.doStuff);
```

then in controllers/user.js

```
    exports.getLogin = function(req, res) {
        //logic...
      });
    exports.logout = function(req, res) {
        //logic...
      });
    exports.doStuff = function(req, res) {
        //logic...
      });
```

Another way is like express-generator way:
app.js

```
...
app.use('/users', users);
...
```

controllers/users.js

```
    ....
    router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      //logic...
    });
    router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
      //logic...
    });
    router.get('/doStuff', function(req, res, next) {
      //logic...
    });

module.exports = router;
```

And other are more dynamic like [this proposal](http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/17/a-simple-mvc-framework-with-node-and-express/)

is there any technical difference? Which pattern should I follow?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and guess this is style preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely preferential. Any pattern that works is likely to be valid here. Express routers make things very nice and easy to setup. Personally I prefer to create a directory for every top level route, files for the second level, and exports for the third. Here's an example of how I lay things out for a set of API routes.

Directory:

```
routes/
  index.js <- master route manifest
  api/
    index.js <- api routes manifest
    books.js
    authors.js
  landing-pages/
    index.js
    awesome-deal.js
```

Route manifest:

```
// routes/index.js
var router = require('express').Router();
router.use('/api', require('./api'));
router.use('/landing', require('./landing-pages'));
module.exports = router;
```

API routes manifest:

```
// routes/api/index.js
var router = require('express').Router();
router.use('/books', require('./books.js'));
router.use('/authors', require('./authors.js'));
module.exports = router;
```

Entity endpoints:

```
// routes/api/books.js
var router = require('express').Router();
var db = require('mongoose-simpledb').db;
router.get('/get/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.param('id');
  db.Book.findOneById(id, function (err, book) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(book);
  });
});
router.post('/new', /* etc... */);
return router;
```

Then in my app file I only setup the the top-level route:

```
// app.js
/* express setup.... */
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
```

Comment: hi, and where do you put the middleware? like a pre-auth check function?

Comment: I don't usually have a ton of middleware so I just configure them all right inside `app.js`. If I had a case where I was configuring a crap ton of middleware then I might move them to another file and in the file do `module.exports = function (app) { /* config middleware */};`. Then I can require it and call it like a function, passing in my `app` object. Then inside there I can setup all my middleware while keeping `app.js` more readable.